# Energy and Power of a Wave: Kinetic Energy Derivation Question Regarding sin function

Tags: energy, waves

[image]

I was following along my Physics textbook for the derivation of the kinetic energy associated with a wavelength of the wave, but

$\frac{1}{4k}sin(2k\lambda)$

disappeared at the end of the equation. Why would it be 0? I am not able to reason out why the wavenumber or the wavelength for the sin function to be 0 in order to 0 that term. Can someone help diagnose what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) well...
$$ 2k\lambda  = 2\frac{(2\pi )}{\lambda}\lambda  $$